# Improving quality of RStudio graphics device (preview)

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

When using RStudio, plots may be examined in the "Plots" pane or the built-in Viewer.
However, I noticed that the quality of these **previews** is worse when compared to a saved plot. Obviously it is possible to export or save the image, with no lack of methods (`pdf()`, `png()`, `ggsave()`, etc).

Using `iris` as an example, the following **screenshot** produces the following plot

```
library(tidyverse)
p.iris = iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)

p.iris
```

[image: Screenshot of Rstudio plot preview]

Compared to the **saved** version of the same plot, with a high DPI.

```
ggsave(plot = p.iris, filename = "Example.png", dpi = 320)
```

While the difference is subtle, e.g. the line from `geom_smooth` is clearer.
[image: Saved version of the same plot]

If inspecting the plot preview, you can see that the plot is saved to a `.png`

```html
<img id="img" width="100%" height="100%" style="display: inline;" 
src="http://127.0.0.1:35473/graphics/c3c6aa95-f458-477e-af54-f443f93ad673.png">
```

Suppose I don't mind additional resources or time being used to render a better quality preview - which settings would I adjust?

Comment: I don't think you can change the quality (things like resolution/dpi) in the display pane, you can really only affect the saved artifacts.

Comment: I was considering that RStudio seemingly saves the preview to a file - shouldn't it then be possible to adjust the arguments RStudio uses to save the preview before displaying it?

Comment: I don't think so, but while I use R every day, I rarely use RStudio. You might get a better response either on the RStudio forums or as an "issue" (feature request) on their github page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could install RStudio >= v1.4 and the package {ragg} and then set the graphic device backend to AGG as described [here](https://ragg.r-lib.org).

[image]

This should make the preview quality better.

Note that this problem is platform dependent. I have the same poor quality of previews on my windows machine, while I have no such problems (even without {ragg}) on my mac.

Comment: Can confirm platform dependence.  Also on Linux, previews are high resolution by default.

Comment: That is **drastically** different - thank you for the answer!