Saving plots in Rstudio/R
I've been using ggplot for the most of data visualizations in R/RStudio.
It's fantastic and absolutely love the package.
However, it always gives me troubles when saving the plots using ggsave() or export in Rstudio.
Fonts are always small when I'm trying to save them in 300dpi, or high resolution.
Saving images through Rstudio's plots -> Export button always give blurr text/ or low-resolution figures if I tried to maintain bigger font size.
Are there any ways or more interactive way manipulating plot elements to get better quality figures, rather than making very long lines customizing font sizes in theme() section?
If there's a package or routine you have been applying to get nice plots, I would like to know and
thanks for sharing!

The camcorder package was made for this. https://github.com/thebioengineer/camcorder It effectively plots the chart using ggsave, but shows it to you in the Viewer for immediate feedback and updates. I also recommend this blog post for understanding font sizes / resolution / dimensions in ggplot2. https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/

If you still happen to use default graphics device, especially in Windows, perhaps consider switching to AGG (from ragg package  - https://ragg.r-lib.org/index.html ) Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410957/646761 and other Q/A-s mentioning "ragg"

No need to manually adjust theme elements if you already like their proportions relative to the plot. Let's say you like the proportions at 400x300pixels in the RStudio plot viewer, just use ggsave(filename = "plot.png", plot = p, width = 4, height = 3, units = "in", dpi = 300). You'll get similar if not identical proportions. Increase DPI as needed for sharper plots. Alternatively, if a vectorized plot is appropriate, output as SVG or PDF instead of a rasterized format like png. If ggsave() is still giving you troubles you'll need to provide some more details or some minimal example code

If ggsave is producing weird results, you can also try using png('filename.png',width=123,height=456,units='px') then print(p) then dev.off()

‘ragg’ solves this issue via its scaling argument. See Taking Control of Plot Scaling for an explanation.

@JonSpring I don’t see how ‘camcorder’ addresses this issue at all. ‘ragg’ does, via scaling.

It sounded like OP wanted to get better figures and a better workflow to do so. “Are there any ways or more interactive way manipulating plot elements to get better quality figures” camcorder makes it a shorter cycle to iterate, by effectively replacing the Plot window with the actual output of your graphics device.

It sounds like you're spending time re-sizing many separate elements. With larger image dimensions and a larger default font size, the quality will be better. Please try using a complete theme function, including base_size = 15 (replacing 15 with various numbers) in the function parameters. For example, try adding
theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +

to your ggplot object. The default complete theme is theme_gray().
Your output will be more controlled if you export the image programmatically (technically speaking, by opening a 'graphics device'). A common format to export to is .png (where you should load the png package). Note that a LaTeX document can import PDF format with \includegraphics{}, and that maintains quality when zooming in. The PNG format is easier to export than the JPEG format. An example:
png(filename = "image_name.png",
    width = 1200,
    height = 800,
    res = 190)
ggplot_object
dev.off()

Note that the res argument is the resolution in ppi, so a higher number will make sizes smaller.
If you're in VS Code, you can pull the image file to the right-hand side, to see the image file update in real-time. Otherwise, you can frequently use an image previewer (such as IrfanView) to preview your image as you update it.
Graphics Devices
The "Graphics_Devices_in_R" lesson in the "Exploratory_Data_Analysis" Swirl course gives an interactive introduction to what graphics devices are, so I encourage you to do that lesson if you are new to this. You can access it with
# install.packages("swirl")
library("swirl")
install_course("Exploratory_Data_Analysis")
swirl()


Perhaps RStudio could preview the image file in the preview pane, but I'm not sure.

The camcorder package helps with iterating figure tweaks by putting the output of the graphics device immediately in the Viewer window.
